# Athena get the minimum value in each group and corresponding other column values

Tags: sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group, presto, amazon-athena

**Input Table**

```
user id action  date           collection

aaa  1   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_1}
aaa  1   view   2020-09-02     {some JSON data_2}
aaa  1   view   2020-09-03     {some JSON data_3}
bbb  2   view   2020-09-08     {some JSON data_22}
bbb  2   view   2020-09-09     {some JSON data_23}
ccc  2   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_99}
ddd  3   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_88}
```

**Output_Table**

```
user id action  date           collection

aaa  1   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_1}
bbb  2   view   2020-09-08     {some JSON data_22}
ccc  2   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_99}
ddd  3   view   2020-09-01     {some JSON data_88}
```

if we see input table and output_table,

i want similar to this

```
group by (user,id,action) then i need min(date) and corresponding collection value
```

**Can anyone suggest an idea?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to flter with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select min(t1.date) from mytable t1 where t1.user = t.user
)
```

Another solution is to use window functions to rank records having the same `user` by `date`, then use that information to filter the resultset:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by user order by date) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```